# Debian php.ini not updating

Tags: php, apache

I can't seem to get my max_upload_filesize to change despite updating the the php.ini file. Here is a screenshot of the loaded config file, upload_max_filesize in the phpinfo() and the php.ini open along side it:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3b3kShpACJHcFV6YU9XMkdyR0E/view?usp=sharing

after updating the file I've tried:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

and I've also tried to stop/start it:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start
```

the phpinfo() says the config loaded is:

```
/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

but when I run:

```
php -i | grep "php.ini"
```

it returns the following:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc/php5/cli
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
```

So I've updated this config file also to 100M and restarted apache, stop and started it again but yet my phpinfo() is still showing 2M max upload.

What could the problem be?

---

UPDATE! I have deleted both the php.ini files on my system in etc/php5/cli and etc/php5/apache2 and restarted but it still says its loading the config from etc/php5/apache2 hos is this possible when I've completely removed the file?

Comment: the problem is, if you run php from command line, it loads another php.ini file. i.e. the one at /etc/php5/cli

Comment: @RaphaelMüller okay but I've updated both config files so that shouldn't max a difference which one is loaded?

Comment: maybe there is some user configuration which overrides your default ones from php.ini. look for a file .user.ini or something similar in your folder where your script lies. it's also possible to override php settings with .httaccess files

Comment: also check if you don't have any `ini_set` sentence in your code that overrides your `php.ini` values. As a last resort, you could use them to set those values.

Comment: Are you maybe running PHP not as `mod_php` but as a FastCGI? Check you `phpinfo` for fcgi or fpm sections. If so, you'll need to modify the FastCGI `php.ini` file on some systems.

Answer (score 0):

Your cli command `php` and your Webserver use different `php.ini` files. That why you have to change both of them.

And you have to change `post_max_size` in your php.ini, too. Otherwise you can't send enough data to your webserver.

Comment: hello @Stony yes I've updated both of them but the phpinfo() is still showing max_upload_filesize as 2M and not the 100M I've set it to? Yes I understand about the post_max_size I have already set this